# Let a thread use only unused computing power

Tags: java

I searched for this and only found "unused imports" "increase of performance" "cloud computing" etc. questions...

So my question is: 
How do I make a thread in java only use cpu power that's not needed for another program? 
I can set the thread to lowest priority, but I still measure relatively high performance drops for other programs running on the computer.

Comment: Lowest priority should do it. How are you measuring "performance drops"? Could memory paging be the issue?

Comment: ah yes it will most likely be memory paging... I'm running an evolutionary algorithm on 4+ threads, with over 1,6gb ram usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the priority is the only thing you can do. How are you doing it? And what is the thread doing? Perhaps CPU usage is not the problem at all, but harddisk access.

Comment: it's an evolutionary algorithm, running on 4 threads, with very much memory usage. i guess that's it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using Windows, but there's a way of starting the whole Java process in low priority: http://www.itworld.com/nls_windows_lowpriority060814